# Keras TimeseriesGenerator: error when checking input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

When I try to use the TimeSeriesGenerator function, my Keras LSTM NN starts training for a few moments but then gives a ValueError message. What's wrong? I wonder how it can start training and then get an error.

My similar implementation without this function runs smoothly but then the quality of the predictions are awful (and I'm not sure that this function, once successfully implemented, would make a difference).

[image: ![starts training]

[image: value error]

See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TerminateOnNaN
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

data = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx',usecols=['wave','wind','current','X','Y','RZ'])
data = data.apply(lambda x: (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x))

n_cutoff = 200
X = np.array(data.loc[n_cutoff:,['wave','wind']])
Y = np.array(data.loc[n_cutoff:,['RZ']])

X = X.reshape(len(X),2)
X = np.append(X, [[0]*np.size(X, axis=1)], axis=0)

Y = Y.reshape(len(Y),1)
Y = np.insert(Y, 0, 0)

n_lag = 3
n_batch = 15
n = int(0.75*len(X))
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X, Y, length=n_lag, batch_size=n_batch)

inputs = Input(shape=(n_lag,2))

hidden1 = LSTM(units=100,
               activation='softmax',
               recurrent_activation='linear',
               dropout=0.5,
               recurrent_dropout=0.5,
               return_sequences=True)(inputs)

hidden2 = LSTM(units=30,
               activation='softmax',
               recurrent_activation='linear',
               dropout=0.5,
               recurrent_dropout=0.5,
               return_sequences=False)(hidden1)
   
outputs = Dense(units=1,
                activation='linear')(hidden2)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

optimizer = Nadam(learning_rate=1e-2, beta_1=0.95, beta_2=0.9, epsilon=1e-7)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(generator,
                    verbose=1,
                    steps_per_epoch=int(n/n_batch),
                    epochs=1,
                    shuffle=False,
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto'),
                               ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto', cooldown=1),
                               TerminateOnNaN()])

Y_hat = model.predict(X[n:])
```

Comment: Your generator is giving `len(X)/batch_size` number of batches. `steps_per_epoch` is the total number of batches of sample to be trained before finishing an epoch. The number of batches your generator will produce should be >= `your steps_per_epoch`. In this case it seems your `steps_per_epoch` is greater

Comment: @mb0850, thank you for the correction. I edited the code with what I understood that should work but it is still returning error. I also tried with ```n_batch = 1``` and ```steps_per_epoch = n``` and it doesn't work.